# Header logo to be aligned with body

Tags: css, wordpress

So the body of my page has some white space on each side, and I would like my header logo to be aligned on the left so that no matter what size the window is, it will vertically start at the same place the body does.
I can not figure out how because the body is centered, but has a percentage width, while my header logo is natively in the middle, and floating it to the left and adding a margin/padding (no matter if it is percentage or pixel) does not make it responsive to larger screens than my laptop.

The css for my container is:

```
.td-container {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1350px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

And so far for my header, I have tried:

```
.td-main-logo img {
    max-width: 1350px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

and:

```
.td-main-logo img {
    max-width: 1350px;
    margin-left: 6%;
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see the full example, not just snippets. Also, you're using tables for the structure? Are you aware that it's a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

Body tag has margin around it. Try to reset it to "hide" white space.

CSS

```
body {margin:0}
```

Tips,

- *margin-left:auto* and *margin-right:auto* is same as **margin:auto**
- try to use *box-sizing:border-box* with **padding** (https://www.google.cz/search?q=box-sizing%20css)

LIVE EXAMPLE: ***http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBMBax***

*(You haven't provided more informations)*

Answer (score 0):

What about this? I have changed the width to 600px just for demo purposes (same the outline)

```css
.td-main-logo,
.td-container {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.td-container,
.td-main-logo{
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="td-main-logo">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" width="100px">
</div>

<div class="td-container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt nihil consequuntur, quasi dicta officiis distinctio, aliquid soluta provident tempore magni temporibus autem, facilis voluptatum ab blanditiis fuga tempora vel tenetur officia voluptate. Quaerat dolor magnam, dolore sint id ducimus ea optio rem nobis doloremque quam animi quidem veritatis assumenda commodi, ratione aspernatur. Ad nemo eos at quis quos saepe numquam, tempora blanditiis minus, pariatur soluta unde dolorem aut beatae esse nam, accusamus dolore rerum quam necessitatibus aspernatur explicabo doloremque. Quae rem error quia facilis deleniti asperiores excepturi numquam illum quo. Eius cupiditate laudantium molestiae ex ipsam perspiciatis, nam! Beatae tempora iure aliquid accusamus illum, adipisci? Ducimus praesentium commodi, aspernatur debitis voluptate omnis nemo quia illo magnam quis voluptates, ullam laborum tenetur dolorum ut. Molestias ex quas ea, excepturi praesentium error, natus ut quaerat porro, tenetur dolorum eaque exercitationem hic officiis repellat est suscipit dolor dolore velit. Doloribus rerum porro deserunt.
</div>
```

`